# Round up in XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath, numbers, number-formatting, xpath-1.0

I'm dealing with a system where a number that is (even barely) over whole should be rounded up to the next-larger whole number.  So

```
<Number>1.2</Number>
<Number>1.01</Number>
<Number>2</Number>
<Number>1.9183</Number>
```

should all be rounded to 2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ceiling()` function. It takes a *number* as an argument and it will replace the number by the next integer which is *larger than* the number.

In XPath you also have the `round()` function which replaces the number by its nearest integer (larger or smaller), and `floor()` which is the opposite of `ceiling()`.

See: [XPath Specification, 4.4 Number Functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Number-Functions)